# How to design users class

Tags: object-oriented-design, domain-driven-design

I have been developing Cloud Broker system so I have Users. Users can register with phone number and code. How should I design the User class?

```
Class User
{
 public string User_Name{get;private set;}
}
```

Or

```
Class User
{
 public string User_Name{get;private;}
 public string Phone_Number{get;private;}
}
```

So should I:

- Add User Name and Phone_Number both in User class and then check authentication with Phone Number
- Add only Phone_Number in User class
- Add Only User Name and convert Phone_Number to User_Name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it is always a good idea for not abusing variables with a specific name for holding completely different data. Do the maintenance programmer (which could be actually you) a favor by **not** putting phone numbers into a member variable called `User_Name`, or vice versa.

So if I got you right, you currently have just one use case where you have to deal either with user names or their phone numbers, where both could be used interchangeably, right?

I would recommend the following:

- if there is the slightest chance that in the next version of your system there might be a new requirement to store both separately, user names and phone numbers, add two different member variables (but allow empty values for at least one of them, and let the authentification deal with it)
- if you know for sure this will never be the case, there will always be either a user name or a phone number to be stored, but never both, then give the attribute a different, more general name, maybe `AuthentificationCode` or something like that. You could also add another attribute for storing the information if the `AuthentificationCode` is a phone number or a user name, in case this matters to your system.

Actually, I find it more likely that for any system where authentification is required, one needs a user name independently of the method of authentification, so you may need a user's name and a general attribut `AuthentificationCode`. But this is something you need to decide for yourself, knowing the overall requirements better than us.

Comment: Thank you for your recommends.I sure will never requirement  to store both.so I think I will prefer general name.

Answer (score 4):

Does not really matter. If you are following an Object-Oriented paradigm, then *functionality* is what you have to think about.

So instead of adding data, think about what this data will be used *for*, and add that to the `User` class. If you want to *authenticate*, then add an `Authenticate()` method.

Hide the data and offer business-relevant functionality. That way it does not matter what data the object holds, it becomes a detail as it should be, and can be changed very easily later if needed.